# How to get rid of nag screen "Authentication is required to set one's own greeter properties"?

Tags: xfce, display-manager, polkit, freedesktop

After a recent update on my Linux system I get a dialogue window every few (5?) minutes with the same message:

```
Authentication is required to set one's own greeter properties.
```

It has a password prompt and "Details" that go

```
org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.AccountsService.ModifyOwn
```

I have never requested a change to greeter settings nor do I intend to.  I also do not enter my password in windows I did not open.

I have tried to find out which process opens this window but did not find anything specific. I suppose it is one of the useless mass processes started nowadays by the `systemd` user session by default.

Perhaps I can stop AccountsService itself, would that help?  Is it needed at all?

The desktop environment is XFCE4.

EDIT: using `xwininfo` and clicking into the window, and then calling `xwininfo -root -tree` shows the following (excerpt from `xwininfo -root -tree` output:

```
xwininfo: Window id: 0x6cb (the root window) (has no name)
  Root window id: 0x6cb (the root window) (has no name)
  Parent window id: 0x0 (none)
     (...)
     0xa42341 (has no name): ()  794x215+87+460  +87+460
        16 children:
        (...)   // no windows with names
        0x18002dc "Authenticate": ("polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1" "Polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1")  786x187+4+24  +91+484
```

Which means this is due to `polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1` (likely started by `/etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop`) but we do not know which process initiates this, right?

Comment: The exact dialogue message you noted is on line 6 of [data/org.freedesktop.DisplayManager.AccountsService.policy.in](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/commit/6015bce25f241e7580c03594d846769f8236232f#diff-92f7d742e56e6196850ba7e42d2c44a5), which is part of `lightdm`. Did your recent system update include an update of `lightdm`?

Comment: @DavidYockey Indeed it was updated. Thanks for spotting that! Of course it is still unclear who calls that method - perhaps it can be (and is) initiated externally.

Comment: None of the issues at https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/issues jumps out at me as being related to your issue, but you may want to take a look and maybe submit a new issue on it if someone hasn't already. It'd be interesting to know if downgrading `lightdm` would serve as a workaround, but I don't know if there's any risk in trying, so use your own discretion.

Answer (score 0):

The solution - or workaround, one could say - for me was to remove the file `/etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop` as root, e. g. by running

```
sudo rm /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
```

When the file is re-generated by an update, I will remove it again.  That does not happen often.

This is not needed for my normal work on the machine so I do not see negative impacts.

Please note, however, that this may influence situations where a graphical window pops up to elevate user privilege (privilege escalation by PolKit and `pkexec`).  If you need that functionality you may not be able to use this.  YMMV.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. Isn't it the generic window that shows up whenever the root password is required?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oh, I do not have use cases for that, I have configured `sudo` where I need it instead of using PolKit. But perhaps this will not work for everyone, agreed. I edited the Answer accordingly. Hope this looks OK to you now, otherwise feel free to edit.